# Can I edit a PCB in Altium, if I only have the Gerber files?

Tags: altium, gerber

I only have the Gerber files; can I open them in Altium, and somehow generate a .pcbdoc file that I can work with (route signal, pour copper planes, place components, etc.)?

Comment: Let us know when you find one, please.

Comment: Gerber files provide you with several layers of routing of a circuit and is mainly the end product of schematic design and PCB design. If you're looking at going "the other way" then it'll get very impractical and time consuming, not worth the trouble. Better to just start from scratch really ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly in Altium, however it's bundled with Camtastic which [can be used](https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/gerber-to-pcb):

```
This is the simplified process.

File ► New ► CAM Document 
File ► Import ► Gerber(s) 
File ► Import ► Drill (Browse to drill file) 
If you don't have a drill file you can create one by placing a via on a new PcbDoc then export it as NC drill
Tables ► Layers (assign the layer types)
Tables ► Layers Order (Confirm the logical & physical Layer order is correct) 
Tables ► Layers Sets (ensure your drill span shows up here)
Tools ► Netlist ► Extract 
File ► Export ► Export to PCB
```

Then a lot of work if you want it to be a normal set of Altium files.

Comment: That is already half way done! I gotta change to Altium.

Comment: @jay You can get a free trial and see if it's actually practical in your particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't as simple as importing the files and editing them directly - Altium cannot, with gerber files alone, determine information such as which pads make up a single component footprint.

Altium does have a help page detailing how you can reverse engineer from the gerbers, though.. [See this page for their documentation, as it's pretty involved.](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/cam-editor-reverse-engineering-pcbs-ad)

Comment: Generally one can tell a pad vs trace by the soldermask or lack thereof.

Comment: @crasic I do agree that was a terrible example. Perhaps a better one would be ability to tell which pads/silkscreen elements make up a single footprint?

Comment: This is true, and a huge limitation of Gerber format even for its intended purposes. However modern production format ODB++ files is also supported by the reverse engineering tool of Altium. This is improvement on current process where  I think almost everywhere common practice is to provide cad files and Gerbers , so generally you will have access to that data in some other format. Exception is  when dealing with PCB fabrication only, that is, without assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Altium PCB does not have a gerber import facility, it is possible to use an external tool and convert to DXF (for example using FlatCAM).

Comment: Welcome! Can you elaborate on your answer (e.g. by directing readers to the right menu option to start the process)? My last recollection of KiCAD (early 6.0) was that it had its own .kicad_pcb format that could be *exported* to Gerber, and it had the ability to *view* gerbers, but not edit them.

Comment: I just skimmed through the documentation. But I believe it may be possible using **Gerbview -> Export to Pcb Editor**, and then using **Pcb Editor** to edit the data. @RobAnderson can you confirm and/or elaborate on this?

Comment: Yes that is the way it works, use Gerbview->export to pcb editor. I just used it yesterday for editing a gerber. Of course it is only for editing the gerber, there are no links to a schematic representation. I used it to change the board shape.

Comment: @RobAnderson I didn't dislike your initial proposal of using KiCAD. The only issue was that it didn't contain much information. IMO you can still promote KiCAD, but then describe how exactly it can be done using KiCAD. That would be worth an upvote from me.

Comment: I am more used to Altium, I have used it for years. But it was easy to use Gerbview to convert the gerbers to a file that could be edited in Kicad. I spent quite a while trying to do this in Altium but didn't get anywhere. I have not used KiCAD for anything before this.

Comment: Gerbview is part of Kicad, I noticed I didn't mention this. FlatCAM is a separate program. These programs are open source and run on Windows or Linux.